# JQuery won't check dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code with a dynamically created group of checkboxes. I need a specific check be checked when I change a dropdown to a certain value. Code is as follows:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(){

    f = $(this).val(); //get dropdown value    

    if(f==9||f==10){ //if dropdown has one of those values
        for(i=0;i<$(".mycheck").length;i++){ //run through all checks   
            if($('.mycheck').eq(i).parent().text()=="TO CHECK"){ //get checkbox label; if match...              
                $('.mycheck').eq(i).prop('checked',true); //don't work
                $('.mycheck').eq(i).attr('checked','checked'); //don't work
                alert($('.mycheck').eq(i).val()) //WORKS!!!
                alert($('.mycheck').eq(i).attr('checked') //returns 'undefined'
            }        
        }

    }

});
```

Any help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: Make an example on JSFiddle where this fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery 1.6+, you should be using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
var checkbox = $('.mycheck').eq(i);
checkbox.prop('checked',true); //should work
alert(checkbox.prop('checked'));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ds3KB/)

Comment: Thanks for answering, however, .prop doesn't work for some reason. I'm using JQuery 1.9.1, which works fine with everything else...